# Adding multiple dicts in dict | python, discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My code:

```
reps = {}

with open("reps.json", "r") as f:
    reps = json.load(f)


@client.command()
async def rep (ctx, member: discord.Member):
    try:

        count = reps[f'{ctx.guild.id}'][f'{member.id}']
        reps[f'{ctx.guild.id}'][f'{member.id}'] = count + 1
        with open('reps.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(reps, f)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('<a:check12:810961073746345985>')
    except:

        reps[f'{ctx.guild.id}'] = {}
        reps[f'{ctx.guild.id}'][f'{member.id}'] = 1
        with open('reps.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(reps, f)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('<a:check12:810961073746345985>')
```

The problem is that when I use this command my json file looks like:

```
{"GUILD_ID": {"MEMBER_ID": 1}}
```

It looks fine but when I try to use this command on a other member json file does not add another dictionary it just changes the name of a dict to a another member id so the file looks like this:

```
{"GUILD_ID": {"ANOTHER_MEMBER_ID": 1}}
```

And what I expect is:

```
{"GUILD_ID": {"MEMBER_ID": 1}}
```

And after using command on another member:

```
{"GUILD_ID": {"MEMBER_ID": 1, "ANOTHER_MEMBER_ID": 1}}
```

Comment: You have this line `reps[f'{ctx.guild.id}'] = {}` that deletes the previous dict saved in that key

Comment: I see, but I still don't know how to make may dict only adding another key without deleting previous keys.

Comment: Simply delete that line

Comment: Check if the `guild_id` key is already in the dict, if it's there add the new member, else create the empty dict as you do in that line.